# In mutual authentication, if a client certificate is known, does it need to be CA signed to prevent a MITM attack?

Tags: ssl-certificate, authentication

Take an example: A povider has setup an API.  Both parties (provider and client) trust eachother. Mutual authentication is required by provider. Client generates a SSL certificate and sends it by SFTP over to the provider. Does that client certificate need to be CA signed to increase security (as in preventing a MITM attack ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, do not sign the certificate as it does not add security.

If anything, it slightly decreases security, because there is one more private key to guard (CA private key).

Both ways require the initial client contact to be authenticated with a separate mechanism, that doesn't change.

Both ways require to match CN field with client's identity, so that trusted client Bob cannot impersonate trusted client Alice.

Certificates expire with time. The main motivation behind CA-signing is to avoid re-distributing renewed certificate over multiple trustees and I assume you only have one trustee (i.e. one server for all the clients). Perhaps surprisingly, my reasoning holds all the same for the server certificate: if you have a single client, you don't gain all that much by CA-signing the server cert.